# RISCV inline assembly compilation

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly, riscv, riscv32

To start with optimizing my code I have to start with adding assembly code into my C which is crosscompiled with gcc riscv toolchain, to start with I trying to implement simple riscv inline as follows

```
int src = 1;
int dst;   
asm ("mov %1, %0\n\t"
"add $1, %0\n\t"
: "=r" (dst) 
: "r" (src));
```

But error while crosscompiling it as

> Error: unrecognized opcode `mov a1,a1'

> Error: illegal operands `add $1,a1'

Should I add any specific flags for inline assembly implementation? any help would be great!

Comment: That looks like x86 AT&T syntax!!  That's definitely not RISC-V; it's `add` instruction takes 3 operands (dst, src1, srcs2), and destination is on the left, unlike AT&T syntax.  You'd want `"addi %0, %1, 1"` as the template, with the same operand constraints.  Anyway, no, there are no GCC options you can use to make it port x86 tutorials to RISC-V for you...

Comment: riscv-spec here: https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual/releases/tag/draft-20220604-4a01cbb provides the RISC-V instruction set.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is not correct, I suggest you to read:

- [Riscv specs on official website](https://riscv.org/technical/specifications/) (riscv specification, these are basically two manuals with all the information about the instruction types, registers, ... everything about the riscv hardware implementation)
- https://riscv-programming.org/book.html (this is a book that I've found about programming in riscv assembly)
- [Computer Architecture Lecture 5: More RISC-V, RISC-V Functions](https://file.notion.so/f/s/d98b6e70-1075-44da-8f11-42808db91b0f/SlidesRiscv.pdf?id=721600a2-b207-488b-b432-8896e65847a3&table=block&spaceId=bfb7bdd6-29b4-4b9e-b63b-d924e9a36c74&expirationTimestamp=1683639934701&signature=U0qJ7L83BlfFDeDe6aTeEkkmPEIOsdVkzJyaPWgvKjU&downloadName=SlidesRiscv).pdf (really good slides to have an idea about riscv assebmly. Here I have also a notion page that I have done to explain a little bit of riscv aseembly to my studentes: [my notion page about riscv assembly](https://www.notion.so/Lezione-4-Assembly-fdc5de6feb6a427796b900382e72fa45). It is all in italian, but there a lot of nice example. It all works on rars simulator)
  And to try riscv assembly on rars simulator, for better understanding on how it works:
- [Ricv Assembler and Runtime Emulator](https://github.com/TheThirdOne/rars)

If you want to use the *move* operatore in riscv assembly you need to use **mv rd, rs** (rd = register destination, rs = register source).

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: RISC-V doesn't need a `mv` for the OP's asm statement, though.  Just `"addi %0, %1, 1"`